# How does one get following solution for $ay''+(x^3y)'=0$?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I'm little confused how one can conclude the following:

if

$$
ay''+(x^3y)'=0
$$

Then

$$
y=C\exp \left(-\frac{x^4}{4a}\right)
$$

where $C$ is a constant.

---

The way I'd go about it, it's clear that $ay'+x^3y=D$ for some constant $D$, and we can apply integrating factor technique, with IF being $\exp\left(\frac{x^4}{4a}\right)$ But then that leads to

$$
\frac{d}{dx}\left(\exp\left(\frac{x^4}{4a}\right)y\right)=E\exp\left(\frac{x^4}{4a}\right)
$$

(where $E=D/a$) which does not seem to lead to suggested solution

Comment: How does that lead to the solution? It looks like that's a step backward

Comment: I believe reducing it to linear first order is the way to go, as you suggested, which does not lead to the alleged solution. Did you try checking to see if the alleged solution is actually the solution?

Comment: Yes, it gets rather messy but somehow magically works to give $0$

Comment: Minor correction: you get $\frac{d}{dx}(\exp(x^4/4a)y)=\frac{D}{a} \exp(x^4/4a)$ (in terms of the first $D$ that you started with). Still, integrating that and dividing out the exponential does not appear to give what you wrote as any of the solutions.

Comment: @Ian thanks, now corrected

Comment: Let $F(x)=\int\exp\left(\frac{x^4}{4a}\right)dx$. Then $\exp\left(\frac{x^4}{4a}\right)y=EF(x)+C$. So $y=E\exp\left(-\frac{x^4}{4a}\right)F(x)+C\exp\left(\frac{x^4}{4a}\right)$.  Thus, one solution (when $E=0$) is $y=C\exp\left(-\frac{x^4}{4a}\right)$ but that is not the general solution.

Comment: I left out a negative sign in the next to last sentence.

Comment: Indeed, what's given looks like a subset of general solution family - it is really confusing because the author seems to regard this so trivially without justification. The only restriction $y$ has to satisfy is that $\int_{\mathbb{R}} y dx=1$, and that it has to be non-negative but that doesn't exclude any of other  possibilites necessarily.

Comment: Actually it does: the other solutions will not have the requisite decay at infinity. This is not very hard to check. (It will help to use definite integrals instead of indefinite integrals.)

Answer (score 1):

$$ay''+(x^3y)'=0$$
Integrating leads to : $\quad ay'+x^3y=c_1$

The solution of the associated homogeneous ODE : $\quad aY'+x^3Y=0\quad$ is : $\quad Y=C e^{-\frac{x^4}{4a}}$

Change of function :  $y(x)=f(x)e^{-\frac{x^4}{4a}} \quad\to\quad e^{-\frac{x^4}{4a}} f'=c_1$

$$f'=c_1e^{\frac{x^4}{4a}} \quad\to\quad f=c_1\int e^{\frac{x^4}{4a}}dx +c_2$$
The general solution of $ay''+(x^3y)'=0$ is : 
$$y(x)=c_1e^{-\frac{x^4}{4a}}\int e^{\frac{x^4}{4a}}dx +c_2 e^{-\frac{x^4}{4a}}$$ 
The bounding conditions are missing in the wording of the question. So, the coefficients $c_1$ and $c_2$ cannot be determined.

Probably, if the solution $y=C\:e^{-\frac{x^4}{4a}}$ is expected, the missing conditions should imply $c_1=0$ and $c_2=C$.